# Rect.ToString() formats with semicolon ("x;y;w;h")

Tags: c#, csv, string-formatting, rect

I wonder if someone can help me.

I have an application that uses a config file to store window locations, when I store the location I get it as a Rect and do a simple `ConfigSection.SetValue("Location", value.ToString());`

99% of the time this string is written as comma separated values `x,y,w,h` however recently a user complained that our app was raising an exception when opening

After following it through I found that an invalid format exception was raised when parsing a window location, I looked into the config file the location had been written as `x;y;w;h,` using semicolon as the separator.

I looked at the regional settings and found List Separator, but when I try changing this to a semicolon (as an attempt to replicate the issue), the rect string is still written as comma separated. This means I am unable to replicate locally and do not really know what has caused the issue.

Any insight as to how the separator may have changed would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Kieran

Comment: "the rect string is still written as comma separated." or as semicolon separated ?

Comment: sorry, not very clear. What I meant is that I was unable to replicate the issue where it would use semicolon separators. So comma separator was correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `InvariantCulture` in:

```
 ConfigSection.SetValue("Location", value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

In the namespace `System.Globalization`.

Then, the format of the string will use a "generic" culture that is exactly the same on all  computers (and does not depend on the settings of the computer).

Comment: Thanks for that, though I cant seem to replicate the issue, if you have any idea how I could replecate it that woudl be great.

Comment: Maybe changing the regional settings of the computer.

Comment: Yeah, I tried List Separator in Regional Settings but no joy. Do you think I need to re-start my computer for regional settings to take effect.

Comment: I don't think so. Normally, regional settings have an immediate effect.